# What do the spinning cards do in 100% Orange Juice?

Tags: 100-percent-orange-juice

In 100% Orange Juice, I sometimes see spinning cards scattered randomly around the game board. I haven't been able to figure out what these cards do or how they are placed, as their effects and location seem to vary.

What do these spinning cards do? What determines where they spawn on the board?

[image: Spinning card]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain cards are trap cards and when used they are placed on the board as a face down spinning card. If a player lands on a spinning card during their turn the card will activate and it's effect will be applied to that player. There is also a Field Event called "Minelayer" that will place a random trap card on the board every 3 turns when active.